# Trying to understand how to write an if then elseif statement using certain parameters

Tags: loops, excel, vba

Yes, I'm a VBA incompetent. Just learning, and I need someone to look at this and point me in the right direction. I want to write an if statement for a range of cells. I want the macro to look at each cell, if the cell = 0, clear cell, if cell <> 0, then do nothing, look at next cell.

Here is my pitiful attempt.

```
Sub MACRO6()
    Dim VM As String
    VM = Range("D29:E43")
    Sheets("10").Select
    For Each VM In Range
        If cell = 0 Then ClearContents
        ElseIf cell <> 0 Then
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `ElseIf` is unnecessary. It will do nothing by default.  Just remove that line.  Because your `If ... Then` is on one line, you also don't need `End If` and should remove it.

You want something like the below (tweaked from [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx)):

```
Sub ClearZero()
    For Each c In Worksheets("10").Range("D29:E43").Cells
        If c.Value = 0 Then c.Value = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ed, you are correct, those are not needed. However, after deleting them my macro did not have the desired effect (it singed my eyebrows). Do you  have any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what that means... what did it do?

Comment: That's a different question -- see above.

Comment: The intent of the question was relatively clear - I don't think its a different question.

Comment: Great suggestion here Ed. 2 followup questions. The first is, if I wanted to make this macro applicable to more than one worksheet, or all the worksheets in the workbook, how would I do that. I tried addidng ("10", "11") etc but it errored saying " "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property". The 2nd question I had was instead of the qualifier being "= 0" how would I say instead "cell has forumla in it that has returned "" (I wrote an if statement in the cell as a formula. Some of the formulas have returned numbers which I want to keep. Some have returned "" which I want to delete.)

Comment: I found the solution to my 2nd question by simply changing "0" to '""'. So no worries about that one. I'm still wondering how to make it applicable to multiple worksheets though.

Comment: For my first question I also tried: Dim wBk As Workbook, wSht As Worksheet followed by: For Each wSht In wBk.Worksheets.Range("D29:E43").Cells but this too errors out on the "range" by saying "method or data member not found"

Comment: That's because you tried to tell it "for each worksheet in this group of cells"...There are no worksheets in that range, only cells. You would have to separate the range part from the `For Each...In...` statement and put it on another line.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this as:

1. You have two ranges to work with, the range defined by `D29:E43` (`rng1` below), and then a loop through each cell in this range (`rng2`)
2. Note that `rng1` has been set directly with reference to Sheet `10` to ensure it runs on the right sheet (and that sheet doesn't need to be selected)
3. You need to specify a range to `ClearContents` on

**code**

```
Sub MACRO6()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Sheets("10").Range("D29:E43")
 For Each rng2 In rng1
    If rng2.Value = 0 Then rng2.ClearContents
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Answers the questions + addresses other issues :)

Comment: On a side note: `.Replace` would be a much better option I guess :)

Comment: Yes - although given this was on understanding and it may have involved `Clear` rather than `ClearContents` I though it worthwhile persisting with the OP's logic.